# Deploying a 32-bit Qt 5.3.0 app (Stand-Alone)

Tags: c++, qt, deployment, visual-studio-2013, configure

I have searched for a long time trying to find a good tutorial on how to deploy my new Qt 5.3.0 app for a 32-bit machine. I have the 32-bit Qt installation as well as all the windows source files (ready for building statically). I've run into tons of problems using various methods to get it to run outside of Qt Creator but I've had no luck.

I need to submit this app as part of an application and would like it to just be the *.exe so I need to statically link the Qt libraries and such.

The tutorial on the Qt website is very lacking in this aspect and I just need a tutorial with the step-by-step instructions on exactly what to do. I am UNABLE to build the Qt source from inside the Visual Studio Command Prompt with this call:

`C:\Qt_Static\qtbase\configure -static -release -platform win32-msvc2013 -opengl desktop`

Where `C:\Qt_Static` is where I extracted the source *.zip file from the Qt website.

After the actual building it gets to a point and says:

```
Running configuration tests...
cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/FS'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 
'"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : 
return code '0x2'
Stop.
Could not find output file: No such file or directory
```

Now, I'm not even sure why its using the cl.exe in Visual Studio 10.0 when I specified VS2013 (i.e. VS 12.0) in the call to `configure`.

My `PATH` variable looks like this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin;
C:\Qt(x86)\Qt5.3.0\5.3\msvc2013_opengl\bin;
C:\Perl64\site\bin;
C:\Perl64\bin;
%SystemRoot%\system32;
%SystemRoot%;
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;
c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;
c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;
C:\MinGW\bin;
C:\premake;
C:\Program Files (x86)\scala\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\
```

If there is anymore information you need to help me with this problem please ask for it and I will happily provide it. Thank you.

EDIT: I just succeeded in getting it to work locally using the `windeployqt.exe` tool, but it is dynamically linked and would have to be "shipped" with all the *.dll's and such which I don't want. I'm about to test it on a computer that has no Qt installation to see if it will run.

EDIT 2: I had to install the latest VC++ runtimes on the testing computer but after that it worked. I still would really like to make it statically linked because it would be much easier to submit for my application.