# compiling Qt using nmake gives Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument ‘/FS’

Tags: c++, qt, deployment, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2013

I’m trying to deploy my Qt application to windows and I’m getting an error when I run nmake about /FS being an invalid numeric argument. It looks like it’s some kind of compile flag that’s not being recognized by the compiler. I have no idea on how to fix this and there doesn’t seem to be any information than what's already provided here http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/windows-deployment.html.

I posted my original question here [Deploying a Qt 5.3 App on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24494251/deploying-a-qt-5-3-app-on-windows)

This person has the same problem [Deploying a 32-bit Qt 5.3.0 app (Stand-Alone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24313275/deploying-a-32-bit-qt-5-3-0-app-stand-alone?lq=1)

I’m on Qt 5.3 with Visual Studio 2013. As both question shows it seems to be running cl and nmake from VS 2010. I’m going to bet this is where the problem lies

Thanks for any help with this problem

Answer (score 4):

Use cl.exe version 18.x to compile.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem and it was me calling the wrong vcvars32.bat from qtenv2.bat, basically was using MSVC2010 with Qt for MSVC2013

As edwinc mentioned, compiler version should be 18.x

Answer (score 1):

Qt 5.4.1, VS 2013. Fixed the issue by editing

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.4.1\5.4\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2013\
```

removing faulty parameter from

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS = -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem trying to compile the deprecated QtHttp and QtFtp modules for Qt5. You're right that the cause of the problem is a mismatch in MSVC compiler versions.  Here are some of the things I found out for others encountering this:

- `qmake` is going to pull in the mkspecs from qtbase.  So if you built Qt with one compiler and try to compile an individual module using a VS command prompt from a different version, it won't care that you used the correct vsvars bat.
- `qmake` can be passed the `-spec` flag to force it to use a given spec. E.g. `qmake -spec win32-msvc2010`.
- Compiling Qt with one compiler version and your app with another will probably compile and link fine. Then it will crash or fail to start when you try and run it, at best.  Worst case, you'll get weird subtle bugs at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you had multiple Qt Kits installed, potentially due to running multiple Qt Creators, switching between kits could lead to such problems. Be meticulous in ensuring that you're using the right Qt Kit and, if it's an auto detected kit, then you're using the right Qt Creator.

With your project opened, review your kit:

1. Options > Build & Run
2. Select Kits tab
3. Ensure your kit is selected
4. In addition consider clicking on "Make Default" to set it as your default kit

   - That kit should now appear in italic bold
5. Do a QMake follow by a Rebuild

Answer (score -1):

Did you try compiling with VS itself? Does it work?

Anyway, try checking C1.dll in your C:/windows/... folder (try searching the directories below it), is it an old one which being created like, 5 years ago? If so, you may want to replace it with a newer version such as those included inside your VS2013 folder.

Comment: There is no C1.dll in C:/Windows/... (and what would that have to do with that compiler flag not being recognized)?. Also what do you mean by "compiling with VS itself"?